# Preg_replace and custom Tags

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system, preg-replace

I have created a custom tag that needs to be stripped out and replaced before a page gets rendered. The tag looks like this: [@ customTagToBeReplaced]

The preg_replace pattern I am using is like this in php:

```
$pattern = "/\[@ .*\]/is";
```

When I have implemented it, sometimes more or less characters are stripped leaving half of an html tag broken. Like this:

before:

```
<div class="">
[@ error]
</div>
```

after:

```
<div class="</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is too greedy, try with something more specific:

```
$pattern = "/\[@ \w+\]/is";
```

`\w` Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).

Comment: It works! Thanks for the tip. Just curious, do you happen to know a good resource for regular expressions?

Comment: I would suggest to read "Mastering regular expression", really a good book (quite big). There is also an online resource that I like very much (http://www.regular-expressions.info/).